# How can I call my class gui_Game from Main via button's action listener?

Tags: java, swing

When I clicked the button named "start", I'd like to launch a class in `gui_Game`.  In `gui_Game` set title and there have three button.

This code is in `Main` class:

```
private class Start implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JButton b = (JButton) e.getSource();
            if (b.getText().equals("start"))
                // I want to add here
        }
    }
```

This is `gui_Game` source:

```
    public class gui_Game extends JFrame{

       private JButton button;
       private JButton button1;
       private JButton button2;
       private JButton button3;
       private JButton button4;
       private JButton button5;
       private JButton button6;
       private JButton button7;
       private JButton button8;
       private JLabel Stage;

       public gui_Game() throws IOException 
       {
          // .. code ..
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
       {
          gui_Game main = new gui_Game();
          main.setVisible(true);
       }
    }
```

In `gui_Game`, it creates a new window and three buttons.

Comment: launch a class in gui_game? so gui_game is a package? I don't think that is possible

Comment: Have ActionListener as an anonymous class inside gui_game?

Comment: `gui_game` - that does not follow naming standards for a class. Have you seen any classes with an "_" or starting with lower case characters in the Java API? Follow conventions and learn by example.

Comment: OP you have to provide us with more details so we can solve your problem

Comment: I added my gui_game source. gui_game is a class

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: 4) Don't extend `JFrame` unless changing existing methods or the necessity of adding new methods. I've yet to see a valid case for extending the frame class, and have developed in Java for around 17 years.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thx!!

Comment: I'd prefer to see an MCVE so we can get on with solving this.. O_o